# Netbeans HTML parsing

Tags: netbeans

In my Projects window I get a red exclamation mark next to a few Java files 
saying: 
"Error parsing File"

However, when I open the class there are no errors and my Project builds 
sucessfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make little changes in files and save files. Repeat this 3-4 times and marks will disappear. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to clean and build? it works for me with these kind or similar errors